# Android - How to get an activity by a PApplet

Tags: java, android, mobile, processing

I have two classes, one that extends from `PApplet`, other that extends from `Activity`.
I wonna comunicate each other by an `Intent`. How do I do this?

## Example:

```
//Class that extends PApplet.
Intent intent = new Intent(this, Test.class); //Activity I wanna go to.
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(this.getActivity(), Teste.class);
    try {
        this.finalize();
    } catch (Throwable throwable) {
        throwable.printStackTrace();
    }
    this.startActivity(intent);
```